Different approaches of rough path theory
This is a soft question. There are three well-known approaches of the rough path theory. The first is Lyons original approach, published in [Lyo98]. The second is an Euler scheme approach, proposed by Davie and is fully made up in the book of Friz and Victoir. The third is the Gubinelli controlled path approach, proposed by Gubinelli and is displayed beautifully in the book of Friz and Hairer.
My question is:

What is the main difference, advantages and disadvantages of the three approaches above?
It seems that, when concerning about the application of rough path theory in stochastic analysis, we take the path regularity $\alpha>\frac{1}{4}$(or $p<4$ respectively). Is there the cases in the field of stochastic analysis when the lower regularity is needed? If not, I think for a probabilist, it is adequet to focus on the case $p<4$ and thus avoid much complexity.

